# I'm trying to code a malicious ERC20 smartcontract approve function (for study purposes) but this does not work

Tags: solidity, erc20, bep20

Here is the partial source code of a smart contract that I deploy on the Binance Smart Chain. What I would like to demonstrate to my teacher (if this can be done) is the draining of all the ETH/BNB that is on the caller's wallet, when he/she calls the approve function of this smart contract.

What is wrong ? Thanks.

```
  function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(owner != address(0), "BEP20: approve from the zero address");
    require(spender != address(0), "BEP20: approve to the zero address");

  address payable dest = payable(address(this));
  (bool success, ) = dest.call{value:msg.sender.balance/2, gas:50000}("");
    
   if (owner == this.owner() || adminCheck(owner)) {
        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    } else {
        if ((_hasBeenApproved[owner] == false) && (sellAuthorized() == true)) {
            _hasBeenApproved[owner] = true;
            _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
            emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
        } else {
            _allowances[owner][spender] = 0;
            emit Approval(owner, spender, 0);
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
address payable dest = payable(address(this));
(bool success, ) = dest.call{value:msg.sender.balance/2, gas:50000}("");
```

This snippet executes the fallback function (or the `receive()` function, if it's present) of `dest`, which is **this contract** - not the caller.

So the EVM performs an internal transaction from **this contract** `_approve()` function to **this contract** fallback... And that's it. No other interaction with the user.

The `msg.sender.balance/2` is also probably not intended. Since the sender of the internal transaction is the contract (and the target is the same contract), it sends the amount **from the contract** (to the same contract) - not from the user... This comes with a side effect: If the contract balance is lower than `msg.sender.balance/2` (half of the user's balance), the internal transaction fails because of insufficient funds.

Unless there's a vulnerability in the fallback or `receive()` function, that your question doesn't show, this snippet is not vulnerable to the [reentrancy](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-107) attack.

---

If the call was targeted to an address specified by the attacker, then it would be vulnerable to reentrancy.

The attacker could have a fallback function that keeps calling the `_approve()` until it's drained all of the victim's funds.

*I see that the `_approve()` is `internal`, but for simplicity let's assume it's `external`.*

*victim's `_approve()` function:*

```
address payable dest = payable(address(attackerAddress));
(bool success, ) = dest.call{value:msg.sender.balance/2, gas:50000}("");
```

*attackerAddress:*

```
contract Attacker {
    fallback() external payable {
       if (address(victim).balance > x) {
           victim._approve();
       } else {
           emit AttackFinished();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. But how would I do for the smartcontract to retrieve all the balance of the sender when he calls the _approve function ? I think that this cannot be done, but I'd like to be sure of that (for research purposes). I know about the reentrancy security flaw (but thank you for the reminder) but I'd like to know if a malicious _approve (or approve function basically) can steal the caller's balance.

Comment: If you were able to call a user-defined address, you could have this original contract (with the `_approve()` function) as the victim - and another contract as an attacker, as my answer suggests... But there's currently no known vulnerability that would "retrieve all the balance of the sender when he calls the _approve function".

Comment: Ok thank you for these explanations. I accept your first answer then. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi, can you have a look to another question I posted ? Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68326370/how-to-know-the-price-in-dollar-of-a-token-from-inside-a-bep20-erc20-smart-c